# Webscraping a table from VegasInsider

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape this table from [Vegas Insider](https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/money/)

I am a total beginner when it comes to web scraping. I have tried a few different ways via stackoverflow but haven't been able to nail it down.

This is as far as I have been able to get.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/money/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
tbl = soup.find('table', class_='frodds-data-tbl')
for matchups in tbl.find_all('td', {'class': ['viCellBg1', 'oddsGameCell','cellTextNorm','cellTextNorm']}):
    if matchups.span is not None:
        gameDate = matchups.span.text
        print(gameDate)

    for b_ in matchups.find_all('b'):
        print(b_.a.text)
```

I'd eventually send these results to a CSV and change the column headers to match the book names on the table. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to load the data into a DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/money/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

# clean-up the cells:
for br in soup.select("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")

df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one(".frodds-data-tbl")))[0]

# set column names:
# df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', ...]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                              0           1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9
0            02/20 1:00 PM  819 Wright State  820 Detroit Mercy   -120 +100  -125 +105  -125 +105  -120 +100  -114 -105  -115 -105  -120 +100  -120 +100  -125 +105
1                    02/20 1:00 PM  821 Michigan  822 Wisconsin   +110 -130  +135 -155  +125 -150  +135 -155  +130 -156  +130 -150  +135 -160  +120 -145  +135 -155
2                     02/20 1:00 PM  823 Providence  824 Butler   -160 +130  -155 +135  -170 +140  -160 +140  -170 +140  -160 +140  -160 +135  -155 +127  -155 +135
3                        02/20 1:00 PM  825 Fairfield  826 Iona  +650 -1000  +525 -750  +550 -800  +525 -750  +520 -780  +500 -720  +530 -750  +600 -900  +500 -700

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: lol, coincidentally enough, Vegas Insider changed their entire site layout yesterday. Any shot you could help me out with the new site? https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/

Comment: @smitty_werben_jagerm Please, create a new question here on StackOverflow - and put there what have you tried so far. I try to look at it.

Comment: hero status right there

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the formatting, you can use `pd.read_html`:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-basketball/odds/las-vegas/money/"
pd.read_html(url)[7]
```